# How to wire-up UISegmentedControl from a prototype cell?

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedControl defined in my storyboard within a prototype cell. Trying to plug the control into an IBOutlet results in the Xcode error "Couldn't compile connection".  After some searching, I found this error message is because IBOutlet can't be used with a prototype cell in this way. Is there a way to access the UISegmentedControl* through the id parameter of an IBAction wired up to the control?  I'll have multiple table rows each containing their own UISegmentedControl anway, so I'll have to put in some logic in the IBAction to differentiate them anyway.

Comment: Do you have a custom table view cell? Is this the class into which you are trying to set up the IBOutlet?

Comment: Yes, I have a my TableViewController storyboard, containing two prototype cells, set to a custom class where I've been trying to wire up the IBOutlet. I've tried putting the IBOutlet in .h and @synthesizing as well as putting in .m but both fail.  Hooking up the UISegementedControl to an IBAction works fine, but trying to hook it up to an IBOutlet results in the error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got this working without IBOutlet. What I had to do was set the tag of each `UISegmentedControl` to some sort of unique number which could be parsed out later when the thing was touched. I did this in my UITableViewController .m file in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. `[mysegcontrol setTag:count];`

Then I wired up an IBAction to the `UISegmentedControl` and within that method did the following:

```
   UISegmentedControl *usc = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;
   NSInteger sidx = [usc selectedSegmentIndex];
   NSString *stxt = [usc titleForSegmentAtIndex:sidx];
   NSInteger tag = [usc tag];

   NSLog(@"control text %@ tag %d", stxt, tag);
```

This way, I can use a switch statement or whatever to determine which `UISegmentedControl` was hit based on the value of `tag`;